# localhost working 127.0.0.1 broken in Safari

Tags: macos, networking, safari, hosts-file

I'm running an http server on a non-standard port on a Mac Powerbook G4 running OSX 10.5.8 and attempting to open a page in Safari 4.0.4. When I use the IP address 127.0.0.1 in the url Safari shows an error:

> Safari can’t open the page “http://12.34.56.78/” because the server where this page is located isn’t responding

where the IP address is the external IP of the machine, so somehow Safari translates 127.0.0.1 to my internet-facing IP. When I use the alias 'localhost' in the URL it works as expected and shows the page.

The /etc/hosts file is as follows:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Any ideas what might be happening here?

Answer (score 1):

[This SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/30827/safari-is-unable-to-reach-localhost-127-0-0-1) has answers that suggest disabling IPv6, among other things.